# What is an efficient statistical test for dependent "different" sets?

Tags: python

I have to do my graduation project and I am facing this question regarding a statistical test.

This is my **question**:

Assume that I have to classify one image by a Neural Network 5 times (5 iterations) and each time it gives me these results:

```
Iteration 1 : class1: 0.0,      class2: 0.5,     class3: 0.5,   class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.

Iteration 2 : class1: 1.0,      class2: 0.0,     class3: 0.0,   class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.

Iteration 3 : class1: 0.5,      class2: 0.5,     class3: 0.0,   class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.

Iteration 4 : class1: 0.0,      class2: 1.0,     class3: 0.0,   class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.

Iteration 5 : class1: 0.0,      class2: 0.0,     class3: 1.0,   class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
```

I need to do a statistical test to know which CLASS is significantly different from the other classes.

My four sets will be:

```
1- class1 values from all iterations = (0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)

2- class2 values from all iterations = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0)

3- class3 values from all iterations = (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

4- class4 values from all iterations = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I thought to use "One-way ANOVA" then "Tukey's test" exactly like here: http://cleverowl.uk/2015/07/01/using-one-way-anova-and-tukeys-test-to-compare-data-sets/

But the problem is that my data is kind of dependent.You can see that each iteration is added up to 1.

For example, in iteration#1, 0.0 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 1. In iteration#2, 1.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 = 1 and so on.

So, which is the best statistical test I can use in my situation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about statistics, which has its own separate [stack exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry for that. I will post the question in the right place. Thank you